# How to systematically detect shapes on an image without using line/shape detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, shapes, vision

I'm working on a project where I have a webcam over a keyboard, and the keys will be detected by it. Below is an image of said keyboard after it has been blurred, greyscaled, and shape detected:
[Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Gc6.png)

Now, the white keys have been detected using standard shape detection from openCV (cv.findContours), and can be done quite consistently between uses, however I cannot get the black keys to be consistently detected each time I run the program (e.g. some of the black keys might be detected one time around, but others will be detected another time around). Because of this, I've decided to see if there are any ways to systematically detect these black keys - any help or pointers are greatly appreciated!

Further information:

- Q, H, O are quadrilateral, hexagon, and octagon respectively and just label the shape of the keys
- I'm using adaptive Gaussian thresholding, but have tried multiple values for the parameters and none of them detect all the black keys, let alone consistently do it
- I'm using Gaussian blurring to remove any noise and have tried different kernel sizes
- I'm using python 3 if that is of any help

Edit: Below is the original image before any processing
[Pre-processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsxzj.png)

Edit 2:

I have now managed to sort this issue out with a much more simple method than I had anticipated. What I did was use adaptive thresholding to separately detect edges for both the white keys and the black keys, as I could tune the parameters more accordingly. Afterwards, I used `cv2.bitwise_or` to combine the thresholded images.

```
threshWhite = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 4)
threshBlack = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 3)
thresh = cv.bitwise_or(threshWhite, threshBlack)
```

Comment: For the black keys, just invert the polarity of the image so that they are white and get the contours of those.  Please post your original image. We might have other suggestions.

Comment: As usual, provide the raw image, we cannot experiment with the annotated one. Anyway, the black keys seem so easy to binarize !

Comment: I've provided the pre-processed image now

Comment: You can try `max(origImg, erode(dilate(origImage))` to get rid of thin black lines. The idea here is that by dilating the image, you will get rid of the tiny black areas. Then you can erode it back (the big dark areas will grow to their original size, while the small black areas are already gone), and combine it with original image, to reintroduce white gaps between the black keys (in case they got removed by erosion) and recover their shape.

Then you can just apply adaptive threshold to get the black keys.